# Linux virtual tty

Tags: linux, serial-port, tty, com, socat

I created my own *Long Range RF USB*.

[USB device] -> [Raspberry PI] -> [myTxApp] -> [RF device *(not WiFi)] -> [RF device] -> [Laptop] -> [myRxApp] -> [Virtual device]

I tested it on *USB Webcam*, and it work perfect, and i can access
   Webcam from any GUI like *VLC*

```
# Tx
gst-launch-1.0 -q v4l2src ! ... ! fdsink sync=false | ./tx

# Rx
dpkg-reconfigure v4l2loopback-dkms
modprobe -v v4l2loopback
./rx | gst-launch-1.0 -q fdsrc ! ... ! v4l2sink sync=false
```

- Now i want do same thing with *Serial* device like *Arduino UNO*, all thing work perfect and i can send and receive serial on *Terminal*, but i can't access serial using any GUI like *Arduino IDE*, i try use virtual tty like *tty0tty* and *Socat*, it works in terminal only and *Arduino IDE* not detect virtual tty :( .
- In windows *com0com* can create virtual serial works perfect and *Arduino IDE* detect virtual serial :) .

To be clear:
How make GUI like ***Arduino IDE*** detect ***virtual tty*** on ***Linux***?

***Solution:***
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23867143/null-modem-emulator-com0com-for-linux
*Arduino IDE* can detect *virtual tty* from *Socat* and *tty0tty* on Linux, just open *Arduino IDE* as root

```
# Ubuntu
$ sudo arduino

# Debian
$ su
$ arduino
```

And now, is there any way to **make** ***Arduino IDE*** **detect** ***virtual tty*** **without** ***root*** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Did you use `socat` as root? If yes, start `socat` as the same user that starts `arduino`, and give correct permissions for this user to whatever other devices `socat` uses on top of the PTY. If you don't know how to do that, please edit your question with the exact commandline you used for `socat`.

2) If (1) doesn't work, have a look at the permission of the PTY created by `socat`, and change the permissions so the user starting `arduino` has access.